# How does GLSurfaceView connect with surfaceflinger?

Tags: android, opengl-es, glsurfaceview

Recently I am confused with GLSurfaceView. In java level, it use glsurfaceview and how it connect with surfaceflinger?

thanks
james.

Comment: https://source.android.com/devices/graphics/architecture.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using GLSurfaceView , you will draw into a EGLSurface which is created from A Surface. The surface ,inside of surfaceFlinger, is called SurfaceTexture with a BufferQueue . Therefore, SurfacFlinger still own that piece of memory the GLSurfaceView will be drawing to and thus could composite it.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4579573/android-graphics-internals). In brief:

- The surface flinger is the compositor and handles drawing `Surface` instances.
- A `GLSurfaceView` contains a `Surface` that can be drawn to using OpenGL ES.